# Local console does not appear on ESXi 6.0 server

Tags: vmware-esxi, console, ipmi

A VMWare ESXi 6.0 server used to be controlled via a serial console, but now has IPMI card with VGA redirection. During the ESXi boot process, there's a running list of "Loading /xxxx.tgz", then "Relocating modules and startup the kernel".  Nothing appears on the (network redirected) screen after that.

I've set VMkernel.Boot.tty2Port to "none", and to "default", but that made no difference. All the relevant services are loaded, and running. Nothing relevant is in the logs.

How can I get my local console back?

Edit: the server runs fine otherwise, just the local console is not available.

Comment: This is interesting. Why are you using serial console for ESXi? IPMI seems like a step up.

Comment: @ewwhite: I *was* using serial console before IPMI card was installed in that server. Obviously IPMI VGA network redirection is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave the VMkernel.Boot.tty2Port field completely blank and then reboot the server.